# i have a problem with sql query building by oop

Tags: php, mysql

when i running this function i get duplicate same array , he doesn't import  all row from data base , just import  2 array have a same row , please help me

```
public function select()  
{  
     $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $this->table_name");

     while ($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
          return $res;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You return on the first iteration, so it will only fetch *one* record.

Comment: [**Do not use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). 
See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? 
Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)
 - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) can help you decide which.